# Zsh -- gulp not working (Error: Cannot find module './lib/argsert')

Tags: gulp, frontend, zsh

After some updates on mac (Catalina 10.15.1), **gulp not working**.
I reinstalled gulp and yarn, but it's still not working and has error
**Command line is Zsh**

```
➜  WorkSpace git:(master) ✗ gulp
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

**Error: Cannot find module './lib/argsert'**
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)

➜  WorkSpace git:(master) ✗
```

Help me please, how can I fix it
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, but if I restart console, problem still on

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
npm set prefix ~/.npm
PATH="$HOME/.npm/bin:$PATH"
PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```